# regexp for find key value pairs separated by colon

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble coming up with a regular expression for a string in the given form:

```
123123<key:value><key:value>,21313<key:value><key:value>
```

where the key:value pairs are optional, but we must not have two colons in the same key:value pairs.

I've gotten this far:

```
^((\d+)(<(.+?):(.+?)>)*)(,\d+)(<(.+?):(.+?)>)*$
```

some valid texts:

- `123131`
- `123131, 123131, 1213313`
- `12313<key:value>`
- `232133<key:value><key:value>,232133<key:value><key:value>`

Comment: A linear string parser would be much better and easier to write and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^((\d+)(<(.+?):(.+?)>){0,2})(,\s*((\d+)(<(.+?):(.+?)>){0,2}))*$
```

Depending on which group you don't want to capture, you can change `(  )` to `(?:  )`.

[Rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/kS4ptsN22P)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this `^(\d+(<.+:.+>){1,2})(,\d+(<.+:.+>){1,2})*$` Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your responses, but none of them seem to do excactly what I'm looking for. I think maybe the easies thing is to follow OrangeDogs suggestion considering maintainability as well...